# How long would it take for a neodymium magnet to demagnetize if it was under the constant influence of another magnet?

Tags: electromagnetism

Not only this but do permanent magnets lose energy when under the influence of another magnet?  I don't need an exact answer, but I have no idea if it would be a couple of days or 10 years.

Comment: To clarify, the other magnet would be of equal strength and would slowly demagnetize at the same rate.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coercivity